# Formal Obligation letter photocopy for Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas

Are there cases wherein an Immigration officer or border guards will ask for an original formal obligation letter from the traveler? My sponsor can only provide a scanned copy of the Formal Letter obtained from his country. He can send the original letter via courier but it will take time.

This letter is for Germany.

Answer (score 1):

This [non-governmental Visa page](https://www.germany-visa.org/verpflichtungserklarungen/) states:

> **The formal obligation letter, must be mailed to you by your host in their original and signed by such host.**

Therefore, the original needs to be mailed to you and you will need to present it to the immigration officer.